# How can i remove underline of word created by android custom Keyboard

Tags: android

i am trying to remove the underline effect created by android custom keyboad like here:

[image: this picture]

how can i remove this 
help me.
thanks.

Comment: turn off auto spell checker by Goto -> Android Settings -> Language & Keyboard -> Spell checker

Answer (score 4):

I think this is feature "auto spell check", you can try

Set this in your layout's xml for your EditText:

android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"

Comment: you are right but i have created a custom keyboard application not for the specific activity that's why i don't have and EditText in my application... thanks

Answer (score 3):

I switched off all the auto correct and suggestion stuff in Gboard (google's keyboard).  Still the line!

So, in Gboard settings - go to settings, language & input then note that Gboard has to be set as the spell checker for the system.  So switch ON spell check to select Gboard, then switch off spell check in Gboard settings (and not system which remains on).